# Why are backslashes used in preg_match function of PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm been practicing the `preg_match()` function in PHP. The tutorial said that it is needed to add fore slashes before the characters.

I also noticed that without the slashes, it works strangely. It gives a warning:

```
preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.
```

**Q: What difference does the fore slashes do?**

Here's the code:

```
$string = 'Okay, I\'m fine with it! ';
$math =  'Okay'; // I need to add fore slashes for it to work
echo preg_match($math, $string); // It supposedly echoes out 1 or 0
                                 // depending if the former argument
                                 // is in the latter argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular reason, it's a syntaxic choice. This syntax has the avantage to be handy to add global modifiers to the pattern:

```
delimiter - pattern - delimiter - [global modifiers]
```

As explained in the error message and in the php manual, you can choose the delimiter between special characters, the most commonly used is the slash, but it's not always a pertinent choice in particular when the pattern contains a lot of literal slashes that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can also apply switches to the regular expression (eg. `m` for multiline, `u` for Unicode) and these need to be defined outside of the delimiter, so the syntax is

```
opening delimiter   expression   closing delimiter   [optional switches]
```

e.g.

```
/^[a-z]*$/mi
```

for the multiline (`m`) and case insensitive (`i`) switches, using a delimiter of `/`

The delimiter must not be a character that can be misinterpreted by the regexp parser, it must be very clear that it is a delimiter, so it cannot be alpha (e.g. `i`, or a `\` that is used to "escape" characters in the regexp

Note that you can also use braces as delimiters, so

```
[^[a-z]*$]mi
```

is valid